# Only cut training and validation data after a complete purchase

Tags: python, pandas, training-data

I am currently training a neural network. I would like to split up my training and validation data with a 80:20 ratio.

I would like to have the full purchases, it must **not** be cut off like this, as a purchase would be roughly divided up:

```
valu2 = round (df.shape [0] / 100 * 20)
print (valu2)
val_mat = train_mat [-valu2:]
train_mat = train_mat [: - valu2]
```

Now my question is how can I split the data 80:20 and that after a purchase.
I would also like to not take the first X purchases, but rather take randomly 20% of the purchases.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

d = {'purchaseid': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9],
     'itemid': [ 3, 8, 2, 10, 3, 10, 4, 12, 3, 12, 3, 4, 8, 6, 3, 0, 5, 12, 9, 9, 13, 1, 7, 11, 11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df.head(5))

[OUT]
   purchaseid  itemid
0           0       3
1           0       8
2           0       2
3           1      10
4           2       3
```

---

```
# Split only 20% of all purchases randomly

mat = sp.dok_matrix((df.shape[0], len(df['itemid'].unique())), dtype=np.float32)
for purchaseid, itemid in zip(df['purchaseid'], df['itemid']):
    mat[purchaseid, itemid] = 1.0

from scipy.sparse.csc import csc_matrix
a = csc_matrix(mat)
print("Shape: " , mat.shape)
print(a)

[OUT]
Shape:  (25, 14)
  (6, 0)    1.0
  (9, 1)    1.0
  (0, 2)    1.0
  (0, 3)    1.0
  (2, 3)    1.0
  (3, 3)    1.0
  (4, 3)    1.0
  (5, 3)    1.0
  (3, 4)    1.0
  (4, 4)    1.0
  (6, 5)    1.0
  .
  .
  .

valu2 = round(df.shape[0] / 100 * 20)
val_mat = mat[-valu2:]
train_mat = mat[:-valu2]
```

---

```
# for example
# Count of all purchase = x = 10
# Split at = y = 20%
#  x * y = z = 2
# Choose z (2) purchase randomly
# Random choose: purchase 1 and 6
```

[image: Better exploranation]

You can see that on the example on the left (which I have right now) a purchase would be cut off. The middle indicates that the purchases are no longer being cut off. In this example it looks the same (but in reality something **could be** cut off) And the right picture shows how I would like it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dirty solution, I'm not entirely sure if this suits your need. In my opinion, the main issue is that 20% is hard to obtain precisely so here's something that will iteratively try to pick the data.

1. Get all UNIQUE purchaseid as 1D NumPy array (I'm not familiar with pandas well enough).
2. Select randomly *n* purchaseid from purchaseid array, n could be from 1-4 or something, up to you to decide. [Generator.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html#numpy.random.Generator.choice) with `replace=False`, this way you will only get a unique purchaseid.
3. Select all rows with purchaseid that you randomly selected and check if the number of selected rows is close enough to your validation split.
4. If not, got back to 2. Else end.